# MySQL SELECT JOIN LIMIT row Comment per Post and LIMIT row Post per User

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate, groupwise-maximum

I have 3 tables in database, ig_user, ig_post, and ig_komentar

```
ig_user
id_ig_user   username     nama
---------------------------------------
1            elizabeth    elizabeth store
2            celmirashop  celmira store


ig_post
----------------------------------
id_ig_post    url_post    username
1             a1b2c3      elizabeth
2             d1e2f3      elizabeth
3             g1h2i3      elizabeth

4             j1k2l3      celmirashop
5             m1n2o3      celmirashop
6             p1q2r3      celmirashop


ig_komentar
------------------------------------------
id_ig_komentar    url_post   nama_komentar
1                 a1b2c3     arif
2                 a1b2c3     budi
3                 a1b2c3     candra
4                 a1b2c3     doni

5                 d1e2f3     ema
6                 d1e2f3     fellaini
7                 d1e2f3     gusti
8                 d1e2f3     hussein
9                 ......     ........
10                ......     ........
11                ......     ........
```

I want select data every user have 2 post, and every post have 3 comment (from table ig_komentar)

I try this query

```
SELECT p1.nama_komentar
     , p1.isi_komentar
     , p1.id_ig_komentar
     , ip.username
     , p1.url_post 
  FROM ig_komentar p1 
  JOIN ig_komentar p2 
    ON p1.url_post = p2.url_post 
   AND p2.id_ig_komentar >= p1.id_ig_komentar 
  JOIN ig_post ip 
    ON p1.url_post=ip.url_post 
 GROUP 
    BY p1.id_ig_komentar
     , p1.url_post 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3 
 ORDER 
    BY url_post
     , id_ig_komentar
```

and return 3 comment/komentar in every post. but, I need user too.

how to query that return 3 comment/komentar in every post and 2 post in every user  like this?

```
username     url_post   nama_komentar
elizabeth    a1b2c3     arif            
elizabeth    a1b2c3     budi            
elizabeth    a1b2c3     candra          

elizabeth    d1e2f3     ema             
elizabeth    d1e2f3     fellaini        
elizabeth    d1e2f3     gusti           

celmirashop  j1k2l3     taufiq 
celmirashop  j1k2l3     uzumaki
celmirahsop  j1k2l3     vivian 

celmirashop  m1n2o3     wahyu           
celmirashop  m1n2o3     xarman          
celmirashop  m1n2o3     yoris
```

username elizabeth have 2 url_post, in every post have 3 nama_komentar
username celmirashop havw 2 url_post, in every post have 3 nama_komentar

Comment: Also, it's a little bit odd to assign a user an id and then reference a different column as the foreign key to another table.

Comment: Please provide the desired output.

Comment: Sounds like a "groupwise" problem; see the tag.

Comment: @RickJames I've edited the question. I put result that I want

Answer (score 0):

Consider a slightly different output, but from simpler SQL:

```
SELECT ( SELECT username FROM ig_post WHERE url_post = k.url_post ) AS username,
       url_post,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(nama_komentar), ',', 3) AS namas
    FROM ig_komentar AS k
    GROUP BY url_post;
```

Comment: your query giving a result, but I want all result as a row, not concat